# Yii2: Change required css class for ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii2

Currently working on a partial view that displays a form (`use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;`). How can I add the 'required' CSS class to a form field similar to the following:

```
$form->field($model, 'user_name')->textInput();
```

Don't want to use

```
$form->field($model, 'user_name')->textInput()->label(Yii::t('app','User Name') . Html::tag('span', '*',['class'=>'required']))
```

because when translating this would require for me to call for a second time `Yii::t('app','User Name')` which is already being translated in my `$model` with

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            //...
            'user_name' => Yii::t('app', 'User Name'),
            //...
        ];
    }
```

is the a way to avoid calling `Yii::t()` for a second time from the view?

Comment: are you trying to add a required `css` class for the fields or you want to show `*` for the required fields on error or by default along with the labels?

Comment: ah yes I want to show * for the required fields by default on and on error along with the labels? What I tried first was adding the option `` to my `$form->field($model,'user_name',['requiredCssClass' => 'required'])` but didn't work

Comment: added an answer see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `requiredCssClass` option inside the `ActiveForm` config like below, if the name is other than `.required` otherwise it is added by default.

```
ActiveForm::begin([
    'requiredCssClass'=>'required'
]);
```

and if you want to show `*` sign along with all labels of the required fields you can add this css

```
form div.required label.form-label:after {
  content:" * ";
  color:red;
}
```

Make sure the classes for label and wrapper divs are same

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks, I even noticed that `ActiveForm::begin(['requiredCssClass'=>'required']);` is not needed if you just add `['user_name','required']` to your `rules()`

Comment: yes you are right, the default class is already `required` i just added so that if your `class` is of some other name you can mention it using the option, be good i updated the answer too @natral